# How to solve this binary optimization problem?

Tags: matrices, optimization, discrete-optimization, binary-programming

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times N}$ be a given matrix. I want to solve the following optimization problem

\begin{align}
\min_{A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}} \frac{1}{N^2}\|(AX)^T(AX)-T\|_F^2 \\
\text{s.t}\quad A_{mn}\in \{0,1\},
\end{align}

i.e, $A$ is a binary matrix. Is there any method or algorithm to solve this kind of problem? I just need some hints and/or references. Thank you.

Comment: what is this in regards to? what have you tried thus far?

Comment: I already know how to solve the problem without the binary constraint. However the solutions I'm looking for must be binary. Any hint?

Comment: two clarifications requested: 1) what is the final $T$? ... I know the exponent $T$ means transpose. 2) What is $F$?

Comment: $F$ stands for frobenius norm and $T=X^TX$